# Small C++ program about months

Tags: c++

I have to create a program that given a number (in this case i have to directly put the number instead of doing cin) will show the corresponding month, but I get the error: "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token" at the line of

Month::Getm(m){

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Month
{ private:
int m;

public:
Month();
Month(int);
int Getm();
};

Month::Month(){m=1;}
Month::Getm(m){
  switch(m) {
    case 1 : cout << "January" <<endl; break;
    case 2 : cout << "february" <<endl; break;
    case 3 : cout << "March" <<endl; break;
    case 4 : cout << "April" <<endl; break;
    case 5 : cout << "May" <<endl; break;
    case 6 : cout << "June" <<endl; break;
    case 7 : cout << "July" <<endl; break;
    case 8 : cout << "August" <<endl; break;
    case 9 : cout << "September" <<endl; break;
    case 10 : cout << "October" <<endl; break;
    case 11 : cout << "November" <<endl; break;
    case 12 : cout << "December" <<endl; break;
    default : cout << "Invalid number" << endl;
    }
}
  //int dias(int){}

int main(){
Month e = Month(0);
cout << "The month is: ";
cout << e.Getm()<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int Month::Getm() { ... }`

Comment: return type <code>int</code>in the definition of <code>Getm ()</code>

Comment: I suggest you put breaks on default cases too, just in case the code gets jumbled up in the future. `Month e = 0;` This code is also valid, you may be surprised to know.

Answer (score 4):

Write

```
int Month::Getm(){
```

i.e., include the return type in the signature and remove the `m` that doesn't belong there because it's not a function argument but a data member.

Comment: How would `m` be interpreted?

Comment: Huh, I didn't even see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that you aren't specifying the return type of `Getm` (`int` in your initial declaration). Furthermore, you have forgotten to specify the type of the argument `m` passed to `Getm`; but do you really want to be passing an argument to `Getm` in the first place?

You have a few problems here...

First, you need to decide what you actually want `Getm` to do. Do you want it to print the name of the month? If so, you should probably give it a better name (i.e., `print()`). The word *get*, however, is generally used to indicate that the method should return something; a string in this case.

`#include <string>` and change your Getm method to this:

```
string Month::getName() const {
    switch(m) {
        case 1 : return "January";
        case 2 : return "February";
        case 3 : return "March";
        case 4 : return "April";
        case 5 : return "May";
        case 6 : return "June";
        case 7 : return "July";
        case 8 : return "August";
        case 9 : return "September";
        case 10 : return "October";
        case 11 : return "November";
        case 12 : return "December";
        default : return "Invalid number";
    }
}
```

You also don't have a `Month` constructor that accepts an integer. It looks like you started to create one, but you didn't finish it:

```
Month(int m) : m(m) { }
```

Your class can then be used like this:

```
Month m(1);
cout << "The month is: " << m.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared member function `Getm` as having no parameter but with return type int.

```
int Getm();
```

And then you defined it forgeting to specify the return type and using unspecified identifire m in the list of parameters (I think you mean data member m of the class).

```
Month::Getm(m){
```

Because the function returns nothing it could be declared like

```
void Getm();
```

and defined the following way

```
void Month::Getm(){
  const size_t N = 12;
  const char *month[N] = 
  {
      "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  };

  if ( m > 0 && m <= N )
  {
      cout << month[m-1] << endl;
  }
  else
  {
      cout << "Invalid number" << endl;
  }
}
```